# Match same character appear multiple times

Tags: grep

I want to use regex to match my requirement that, for a same character, it appeared 3 times with exactly one other character inserted into them (to simplify the answer assume all chars are in `[a-zA-Z]`).

For eg `popape`, `ccccAjAkA` meet my requirement, but `KKKccc`, `FFFsF` (not an 'other' char between two 'F's) are not qualified. how can I write this `grep` command?

Comment: How does `FFFsF` not contain `FsF` matching the requirement?

Comment: Wait, you're searching for XaXbX (X being any character and a and b being some character != X but possibly the same)?

Comment: @BodoThiesen I THINK `FsF` doesn't match because that's 2 `F`s, not 3, with another character between them. I THINK `FFFsFsF` would match because it contains `FsFsF`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yea, bottom line is: OP should update his question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using (experimental in `grep`) Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE):

```
grep -P '([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)(.)\1(?!\1)(.)\1'
```